# Listen for key input from editor script

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I am using an editor script placed in editor folder, which listens to a key pressed. When the key is pressed, it is supposed to trigger a function from `MonoBehavior` script. The issue is that the function does not get triggered at all. I am even adding `EventSystem` in my inspector. What is the problem here? :

```cs
[CustomEditor (typeof (Switcher))]
public class SiwtcherEditor : Editor {
    void OnSceneGUI () {
        Switcher script = (Switcher) target;
        Event e = Event.current;
        switch (e.type) {
            case EventType.KeyDown:
                {
                    if (Event.current.keyCode == (KeyCode.A)) {
                        Debug.Log ("A pressed");

                        script.SwitchHere();
                        e.Use ();
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }
}
```

```cs
public class Switcher : MonoBehaviour {
    public void SwitchHere () {
        Debug.Log ("GotINPUT"); 
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you mean it "_should_" trigger a function, but it isn't?

Comment: Yes. Even the Debug.Log("A Pressed") in my editor script is not getting called . The problem is there.

Comment: Can someone point out the mistake?

Comment: Are you getting any exceptions?

Comment: No errors or exceptions at all

Comment: Try to add recheck before the switch : if (e != null)

Comment: @Kamiky I added that as well but nothing happens. I even tried to add Debug.Log() but there was no output. I am adding the editor script inside Editor folder and the main script to a gameObject.

Comment: I feel the OnSceneGUI () does not get called at all.

Answer (score 3):

If someone comes across this problem, the issue was that OnSceneGUI() was not getting called. So the problem is resolved by OnEnable() function as given below:

```
[CustomEditor (typeof (Switcher))]
public class SiwtcherEditor : Editor {
    void OnSceneGUI (SceneView sceneView) {
        SceneView.RepaintAll ();
        Switcher script = (Switcher) target;
        Event e = Event.current;
        switch (e.type) {
            case EventType.KeyDown:
                {
                    if (Event.current.keyCode == (KeyCode.A)) {

                        script.SwitchHere();
                        e.Use ();
                    }
                    break;
                }
        }
    }

 void OnEnable () {
        SceneView.duringSceneGui += OnSceneGUI;
    }

    void OnDisable () {
        SceneView.duringSceneGui -= OnSceneGUI;
    }
}
```